# What's the equivalent of Bonjour for Windows

Tags: windows, mac

The Mac has "Bonjour".
Whats the equivalent on Windows?

Comment: According to wikipedia, Win2000, 2003, XP, and Vista is supported: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28software%29

Answer (score 14):

You can get [bonjour for windows](http://support.apple.com/downloads/Bonjour_for_Windows)

Answer (score 7):

Bonjour is an implementation of [Zeroconf (Zero Configuration Networking)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroconf), which consists of the protocols mDNS (Multicast DNS) and [DNS-SD (DNS-Service Discovery)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS-SD).  mDNS provides "link-local addressing", while DNS-SD is a means for devices to discover services provided by other devices on the network.

While there is a Windows version of Bonjour, Microsoft does have its own implementation of zero-configuration networking that isn't exactly the same.

Here's Wikipedia on Zeroconf:

> Both versions of the Internet Protocol, IPv4 and IPv6, have standard
>   methods of automatically configuring network interface addresses
>   through a method called address autoconfiguration. IPv4 uses the
>   169.254.0.0/16 (link-local) set of addresses defined in RFC 3927. In
>   IPv6, both link-local addresses and global unicast addresses may be
>   automatically self-configured by a host, see RFC 4862.
>
> The technique is called **Link-Local address assignment** in RFC
>   3927. However, Microsoft refers to this as **Automatic Private IP
>   Addressing** (APIPA) or **Internet Protocol Automatic Configuration**
>   (IPAC) (supported since at least Windows 98).

[UPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) is a separate architechure, considered a competitor in some ways and an altogether different technology in others.  It supports a form of zero-configuration networking but doesn't use the mDNS/DNS-SD protocols that Apple utilizes.  UPnP provides a service discovery protocol called [Simple Service Discovery Protocol (SSDP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol) that is a rough equivalent to DNS-SD.

In particular, Wikipedia's [Zeroconf article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroconf), [UPnP article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play), and the [O'Reilly Zeroconf-vs-UPnP article](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/wireless/2002/12/20/zeroconf.html) (from chills42's comment) are the best references for comparing the two and getting a feel for how they differ.

Answer (score 6):

Bonjour!  It runs on Windows too.  Here's a [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)#Microsoft_Windows_implementation) to the wikipedia entry, you can read more starting there.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent for Bonjour in Windows is Universal Plug and Play. It has been part of Windows sinds XP.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play

Comment: Similar purpose, but fairly different technology, see the comparison here: http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/wireless/2002/12/20/zeroconf.html